# eclipse error “com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException” when useing tomcat+JSP+JDBC for deleting a MySQL column

Tags: mysql, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I have limited experience with Servlet, and I want to click the botton **AllDelete** like this 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qt0H.jpg), but it has an error in eclipse:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-6,6' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3124)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1149)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1262)
    at com.newsmanager.dao.NewsDao.getNewsList(NewsDao.java:92)
    at com.newsmanager.servlet.NewsServlet.doPost(NewsServlet.java:75)
    at com.newsmanager.servlet.NewsServlet.doGet(NewsServlet.java:21)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Servlet Java code:

```
else if ("allDelete".equals(oprate)) {
    String[] deleteId = request.getParameterValues("deleteId");
    if (deleteId != null) {
    //the parameter might have more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).
    //And getParameterValues returns a String[];22
    for (String string : deleteId) {
        Integer Did = Integer.valueOf(string);
        NewsDao.deleteNewsBYId(Did);

    }
    }
    response.sendRedirect("NewsServlet");

}
```

JSP code:

```
<input type="submit" value="AllDelete" />
     <input type="hidden" id="oprate" name="oprate" value="allDelete" />
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="deleteId" value="${news.newsId}" /></td>
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

part of code from NewsDao.java

```
public List<News> getNewsList(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
List<News> NewsList = new ArrayList<News>();
conn = DbConn.getconn();
try {
    int startSize = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
    String sql = "select * from news limit " + startSize + "," + pageSize;
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

Comment: The code shown is not the code that produces the error. The problem is in `com.newsmanager.dao.NewsDao.getNewsList(NewsDao.java:92)` and by the looks of the error, you either have an error in the query itself, or you are concatenating values into the query string instead of properly using parameters.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely :),and I have add part code from NewsDao.java,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Given the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-6,6' at line 1

and the code shown, you are trying to execute the query

```sql
select * from news limit -6,6
```

The [syntax for `limit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}`. A negative value is not allowed for offset (nor for rowcount), as that would result in you asking for rows before the first row (which of course is not possible). As such the MySQL syntax requires you to provide an unsigned integer value, providing a negative value is a syntax error.